# node.js RSS memory grows over time despite fairly consistent heap sizes

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I've got a node.js application where the RSS memory usage seems to keep growing despite the heapUsed/heapTotal staying relatively constant.

Here's a graph of the three memory measurements taken over a week (from `process.memoryUsage()`):

[image: memory graph]

You may note that there's a somewhat cyclical pattern - this corresponds with the application's activity throughout each day.

There actually does seem to be a slight growth in the heap, although it's nowhere near that of the RSS growth.  So I've been taking heap dumps every now and then (using node-heapdump), and using Chrome's heap compare feature to find leaks.
One such comparison might look like the following (sorted by size delta in descending order):

[image: heap dump]

What actually shows up does depend on when the snapshot was taken (eg sometimes more Buffer objects are allocated etc) - here I've tried to take a sample which demonstrates the issue best.

First thing to note is that the sizes on the left side (203MB vs 345MB) are much higher than heap sizes shown in the graph.  Secondly, the size deltas clearly don't match up with the 142MB difference.  In fact, sorting by size delta in ascending order, many objects have be *deallocated*, which means that the heap should be smaller!

Does anyone have any idea on:

- why is this the case? (RSS constantly growing with stable heap size)
- how can I stop this from happening, short of restarting the server every now and then?

Other details:
Node version: 0.10.28
OS: Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit

Update: list of modules being used:

- [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) v0.2.6
- [log4js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/log4js) v0.6.2
- [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) v2.0.0-alpha7
- [nodemailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/) v0.4.4
- [node-time](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time) v0.9.2 (for timezone info, not to be confused with nodetime)
- [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) v0.3.8
- [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) v1.4.4
- [usage](https://github.com/arunoda/node-usage) v0.3.9 (for CPU stats, not used for memory usage)
- [webkit-devtools-agent](https://www.npmjs.org/package/webkit-devtools-agent) v0.2.3 (loaded but not activated)
  [heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump) v0.2.0 is loaded when a dump is made.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What modules are you using? Are any of them compiled addons?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added list of modules above.  I believe only node-time, webkit-devtools-agent and heapdump are compiled modules, with node-time the only one being actively used.  node-time's compiled component is a very simple time.h wrapper.

Comment: @zinga Did you find what was the reason for this?
Suffering from the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not - the issue actually got worse when I updated to node v0.12, then went away when I moved to node v4.  No additional compiled modules added, so I'm blaming node for the memory leak.  If you think it isn't a compiled module, try different versions of node I guess...

Comment: We're still investigating a similar issue, but we did came across this:

_Usually, only arrays and strings can have a significant shallow size. However, strings and external arrays often have their main storage in renderer memory, exposing only a small wrapper object on the JavaScript heap._

[Source can be found here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101) Under the __Shallow Size__ section.

Answer (score 2):

The difference you see between RSS usage and heap usage are buffers.

"A Buffer is similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap"
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Buffers actually show up in the heap dump though (including space used), and they don't explain the difference.

It definitely won't be the whole difference obviously - node, V8 and other native code consume memory themselves, which increases RSS without increasing the JS heap size.